# Putty exectes my php script without error but no results

Tags: php, excel, oracle

Putty executes my php script without error but no results. This script is supposed to run a query on the database and the send those results as excel file. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: So start doing some debugging, break things down into steps: see if the query is being executed successfully first, if it is, see if the excel file is being generated correctly, if it is, look at the code to send

Comment: For correctness, PuTTY is not executing anything. Assuming you are using the SSH client, its purpose is to pass your commands to the server (so the server can execute your script) and to pass server output back to you in the form of console output.

Comment: Maybe your mail sending is broken? That is often the cause of these problems. **If it is safe to do so** edit the file on the server with `echo` statements to see where it is getting stuck. If that is not safe, copy the file to your local machine, and debug it there.

Answer (score 2):

Try prepending your script with:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

to output all errors. Failing that, you could put some debug in the code to find where it keeps failing.

Sometimes there is something in the PHP error log (`/var/log/php_errors` on Centos).

Comment: I had error reporting turned off... I changed that and now I am getting the error...It says 'PHP Warning:  ocilogon(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred '. I am wondering how i am gonna fix this. Since some automated reports are running well on the sam server. Any suggestions will be welcome.